# php substr delete?

Tags: php, string, numbers, substring, substr

I have an game ip in my database, like so: `"271.29.248.23:27912"`

I want the substring to take the last 5 numbers "`27912`" and also i want to delete the `":"`.
Is that possible and could someone help me?

And if possible i would like the numbers to be like this so it would be easier...

```
$ip = "271.29.248.23";
$port = "27912";
```

Please help me, i need this for a script :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 list($ip, $port) = explode(":", "$your_string:");
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, i will test it out :)

Comment: `$your_string . ':'` would be cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), which will handle more cases:

```
$url = "271.29.248.23:27912";
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [host] => 271.29.248.23
    [port] => 27912
)
```